# unity3d - Camera jittering?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, jitter

For some reason when I run my game the camera which follows the player has a slight jitter to it. If I watch the transform the Y position values are fluxuating and the rotation is affected aswell. I can not think of any reason for this to be happening other than maybe having more than one camera as my water comes with a 'reflection camera'. I am using basic unity packages, and even when rewriting the camera follow script, the problem still occurs.

I know there is not much to go on here, as the code is minimal for this issue(using 3rd person controller and camera components). I hope someone has had this error in the past and fixed it or knows enough about unity to help me out here because im lost.

Much appreciated

**EDIT**

Dont know if animations could be effecting it but I thought id mention my model has animations

Comment: Which one is the parent? the Camera or the Object?

Comment: Have you tried toggling VSync on or off? Does it happen in both the Editor and compiled/built standalone player, or only one or the other?

Comment: The camera has a target that it looks at which is the player

Comment: And im not sure what VSync is, but it happens both in the editor and built version

Comment: VSync is locking your FrameRate depends on your Monitor. This is not the problem. If you make your Camera a child or a parent to a Euler moving character. You are bound to have a jitter.

Comment: You're problem can be fixed without even coding actually.

Comment: Im not sure if it is a parent or child of it, the only connection between the two is the target parameter in which I take in so the camera script can follow it. Does this mean its parented? I am following a guide and he is not having this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve your problem. Click Assets->Import Package-> Characters Uncheck everything Execpt. SmoothFollow.

Drag Smooth Follow to your Camera. Drag your Character to the Target from Smooth Follow Script.

If this doesn't fix the issue. Try to remove your own script.

Comment: I realized it was an old line in a seperate code that was hiding from me. It was setting the position seperately to follow the player after every frame. I removed it and all was good :) Although this would work aswell, so I will accept it :)